# Issue with combo box within Access form

Tags: ms-access

I'm playing around with the form builder in Access, and I'm running into some issues when it comes to filtering a query based on the combo box selection. Right now I'm just trying to do something simple, where I choose a list of names from the combo box, hit the command button, and receive results based on what selected in the combo box. Unfortunately, every time I select an option from the list and hit the command button, it returns no results. I've followed countless tutorials, and I've yet to get this to work, so obviously I'm missing something simple. I've tried to outline what my setup looks like down below. If additional information is needed just let me know.

1. The drop down combo box is connected to my `Client_List` table in order to get the list of clients(This is working fine).
2. Combo box itself is named `clientDropDown`.
3. The Command Button is named `Command3` and it's connected to an event macro that runs `Query test`
4. The form is saved as `Test1`

Query test looks like this:

```
SELECT Client_List.Client_Name, Client_List.End_of_Bill_Date, Client_List.Data_Availability_Date
    FROM Client_List
         WHERE (((Client_List.Client_Name)=[Forms]![Test1]![clientDropDown]));
```

Is there something I'm missing, another step I need to follow? Like I mentioned before, if I left out any key bits of information, just let me know and I'll provide it.

Comment: When you say the command button macro runs `Query test`, does that mean you're opening the query in Datasheet View, equivalent to what you would see with `DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query test"`?

Comment: @HansUp Yes it opens up in Datasheet View.

Comment: Then when you open `Query test` in the Access query designer and run it, it also returns no records there.  Correct?

Comment: @HansUp correct, although my thought was that since I was opening up in the query designer, then maybe it wasn't accessing the information from the form and that is why it was returning no records. Then again, what do I know lol?

Comment: If the form is open in Form View, the db engine can retrieve the combo box value, so I don't believe that is the issue.  My guess is the combo box `.Value` property is not what you expect.  Please check.  Go to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g will take you there), paste in this highlighted text, and press Enter: `Debug.Print [Forms]![Test1]![clientDropDown]`  Does that show you a match for one of your `Client_Name` values or something else ... perhaps a number or some unexpected text string?

Comment: @HansUp It gives me an error saying `Run-Time error '2186' This property isn't available in Design view`

Comment: Switch the form to Form View not Design View and try again.

Comment: My mistake, I misread your comment. It returns `1`

Comment: Good.  Can I assume `1` does not match any of your `Client_List.Client_Name` values?

Comment: Correct, It looks like it's pulling from the `ID` rather than the name. When I changed the SQL where clause to ``WHERE (((Client_List.ID)=[Forms]![Test1]![clientDropDown]));` It returned the name I that corresponds with that number.

Comment: Yes, the combo `.Value` is determine by its *Bound Column* property --- so it appears your combo has its `ID` column set as its *Bound Column*.  If you're happy with your revised query, I think we're done.  Please submit your solution as the answer.

Comment: @HansUp Without your help I would have never gotten there, if you want to submit the your comments about the Bound Column as the answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: My point was I prefer you do it.  I don't want to invest any more of my time on this one.